# How to visualise percentages of two circles? Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying the create a circle with different percentages in colours in a ring shape. See below. As you can see the shapes even have sometimes little ends or notice the green part inside the ring. How would I make this? [image]

Comment: Can you share what you’ve tried and where you’re struggling? Seems like this should be fairly straightforward if you use the pie chart tool as a starting point.

Comment: @Westside this is one of those things where even using notepad is less workthan 5 minutes

Answer (score 5):

Just set up some guides with some circles and lines...

[image]

Then use the Shape Builder tool to construct your desired shapes...

[image]